# Sum of tree in haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, sum

I tried the following code but I get an error that *`a`* is not matched with the expected type "`Integer`".

```
data Tree a = Tip | Bin (Tree a) a (Tree a)

sumTree :: Num a => Tree a -> a

sumTotal = 0
sumTree Tip = 0
sumTree (Bin l a r) = (sumTotal+ a)+ sumTree l + sumTree
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Haskell there are no mutable variables, so `sumTotal` and `sumTotal +`  make no sense. Normally in Haskell one makes use of recursion as mechanism to visit the items in the tree. You thus can implement  `sumTree` as:

```
sumTree :: Num a => Tree a -> a
sumTree Tip = 0
sumTree (Bin l a r) = a + sumTree l + sumTree r
```

For a tree with two levels, this will thus perform recursion on the left and right subtrees. For a tree like `Bin (Bin Tip 1 (Bin Tip 4 Tip)) 2 (Bin Tip 5 Tip)` this will thus evaluate this as:

```
   sumTree Bin (Bin Tip 1 (Bin Tip 4 Tip)) 2 (Bin Tip 5 Tip)
 → 2 + sumTree (Bin Tip 1 (Bin Tip 4 Tip)) + sumTree (Bin Tip 5 Tip)
 → 2 + (1 + sumTree Tip + sumTree (Bin Tip 4 Tip)) + sumTree (Bin Tip 5 Tip)
 → 2 + (1 + 0 + (4 + sumTree Tip + sumTree Tip)) + sumTree (Bin Tip 5 Tip)
 → 2 + (1 + 0 + (4 + 0 + sumTree Tip)) + sumTree (Bin Tip 5 Tip)
 → 2 + (1 + 0 + (4 + 0 + 0)) + sumTree (Bin Tip 5 Tip)
 → 2 + (1 + 0 + 4) + sumTree (Bin Tip 5 Tip)
 → 2 + 5 + sumTree (Bin Tip 5 Tip)
 → 2 + 5 + (5 + sumTree Tip + sumTree Tip)
 → 2 + 5 + (5 + 0 + sumTree Tip)
 → 2 + 5 + (5 + 0 + 0)
 → 2 + 5 + 5
 → 7 + 5
 → 12
```

You can also make `Tree` an instance of `Foldable` with the [**`DeriveFoldable`** extension [ghc-doc]](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.2.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XDeriveFoldable) (or by implementing the `Foldable` instance yourself). In that case  `sumTree` is just a special case of [**`sum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data Tree a = Tip | Bin (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving Foldable

sumTree :: Num a => Tree a -> a
sumTree = sum
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's such a stupid mistake. Thank you for explaining it so neatly

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the reference to `sumTotal` which gets a monomorphic type while being used in the polymorphic function `sumTree`.

You also have a copy-paste typo in the post, in

```
sumTree (Bin l a r) = (sumTotal+ a)+ sumTree l + sumTree
```

but you actually must have

```
sumTree (Bin l a r) = (sumTotal+ a)+ sumTree l + sumTree r
```

in your code or else you'd be getting  a different error.

---

But `sumTotal` is actually not needed at all, as it is always `0`, so it changes nothing. You can just remove it altogether from everywhere, and when you do, the error will go away, and the function will just work.

But adding `0` shouldn't hurt, you ask? Right, but with the restriction, the variable `sumTotal` gets a monomorphic i.e. specific type, like `Integer`. And your function `sumTree` is declared polymorphic, so stays that way. Adding a fixed type value to a flexible type value makes no sense.

In Haskell there are no type casts changing a value at run-time. All types are known in advance. When we add two "flexible", polymorphic type values together, the result is the same type, so when it is actually decided what specifically that type will be, it will be assigned to all three occurrences in unison. But when you use a specific type from the get go in one of them, you prevent that synchronicity.

But still, adding `0` shouldn't break things, you say. What could be done to avoid the error without changing the code?

For that, you need to disable the monomorphism restriction.

In GHCi, use

```
> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
```

and then enter your definitions anew, in multi-line input mode, with `:{` and `:}` commands.

Or in your source code file add

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

at the very top.